# Modify html element dinamically with jquery-ajax response not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'll go to the point directly:

I have a site that makes a request to a server and retrives some data. This data is "painted" into a already created table, namely, a function updates de table inserting de data retrieved from the server.

I retrieve a json from the server and I parse each element:

```
$.each(data, function(index, element){
```

then I add the element to the table using .append() jquery's method.

```
$(".clndr-table td").filter(function(){
    return ($(this).text() == fechaS.getDate() && !$(this).hasClass("adjacent-month"));   
}).append(textToInsertD);
```

The problem is that if there is more than one element that needs to be appended to the same td, only the last one read is appended. I think that this filters the empty table the first time and doesn't 'save' the elements added after create the table and before read the last element.

Maybe I have to use .on(), but I don't know how to use is exactly, the only examples I saw where on click events but... here? Or maybe thats not the error...

Thanks in advance, and tell me if you need more code or more explanations, I don't know if I'm explaining correctly.

EDIT: I'll add more code, this method is called when the page is loaded:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function(index, element){
                    var fechaS = parseDate(element.fechaSis);
                    var fechaP = parseDate(element.fechaProy);

                    var textToInsertD = '<div class="delivery">' + element.version + ' (D)</div>';
                    var textToInsertP = '<div class="delivery-proy">' + element.version + ' (P)</div>';

                    if(month == fechaS.getMonth()+1){
                            $(".clndr-table td").filter(function(){
                                return ($(this).text() == fechaS.getDate() && !$(this).hasClass("adjacent-month"));   
                            }).append(textToInsertD);
                        }
```

**EDIT2:**

changing the filtering part seems to work well:

```
$(".day-contents").filter(function(){
    return ($(this).text() == fechaS.getDate() && !$(this).hasClass("adjacent-month"));   
}).parent().append(textToInsertD);
```

Comment: `on` is only used for events (or delegated events), so that is not the answer. Still not sure what the actual question is without more of the example. please provide more code and example HTML perhaps?

Comment: Without the full code this is a guess, but it looks like you you are filtering which TD to insert into, *based on the entire text content*. That means that the moment you append anything, the next filter call will not match that TD as its text value has changed.

Comment: But the td is created before. Well is a calendar, I create the calendar, and then I add some information to the days td.

Comment: Can you please save a snippet of the page's HTML (e.g. from a browser)? Otherwise we have to imagine the content. Thanks

Comment: Ok, with this "the next filter call will not match that TD as its text value has changed." you help me. I was checking the day, after that, I inserted the div, and somehow, when it checked again, It wasn't working properly. I'll add above the changes I did. Thaaank you